# Get and show all of the available categories

Tags: categories

I know that there are a few ways of doing this but for everything that I have tried I can only manage to get the first category. For example:

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
```

Only shows one. Like:

```
<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
        echo $category->name."<br>";
        echo category_description($category);
        }
 ?>
```

Shouldn't this functions get me the full list of existing categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be noted that both

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
        echo $category->name."<br>";
        echo category_description($category);
        }
 ?>
```

display ALL categories that are assigned to the current post in the loop.

From your question's title, I understand that you want to display all available categories that exist in the website, so `wp_list_categories()` is more suitable. So using:

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories(); ?> 
</ul>
```

will return a list of all categories that have been assigned to at least one post. You can see the documentation for the function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

Comment: Yep, that was my issue, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.
Please check if you have post assigned to your categories.
Category should not be displayed if empty.

Comment: wp_list_categories(); did the trick but I don't understand why the category list wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked and displayed all of the categories:

```
wp_list_categories();
```